# Forced to include a reference to a dll

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

Scenario : ProjectA Reference ProjectB, and ProjectB references ProjectC

I have an interface defined in ProjectC

```
namespace Cmp.Product.Family.Configuration.Container
{
  public interface IComponent
  {
    // a couple of methods
  }
}
```

In ProjectB (ProjectB depends on ProjectC) I do this:

```
using Cmp.Product.Family.Configuration.Container;

namespace Cmp.Product.Family.UI
{
    public interface IPublicComponent :  IComponent
    {

    }
}
```

So far so good. However the problem is that ProjectA can't compile. The compiler complains that the

> Cmp.Product.Family.Configuration.Container.IComponent is not defined. Add a reference to ProjectC.

I don't understand why I need to add a reference to ProjectC. I still didn't use the `IPublicComponent` in ProjectA.

I couldn't reproduce this problem on a smaller repro. Is there a way to have a verbose output from the C# Compiler?

Hint : The class where the problem appears in ProjectA a nested namespace (`namespace Cmp.Product.Family.UI.Settings`). The problem goes away if I change the namespace in the defintition of the `IPublicComponent`.

EDIT :

If I change the name that contains IPublicComponent from :

```
 Cmp.Product.Family.UI
```

to :

```
 Cmp.Product.Family.SomethingElse
```

that helps. Knowing that the class where the problem is in ProjectA is container in this namespace :

```
Cmp.Product.Family.UI.Settings
```

Answer (score 4):

ProjectA needs ProjectC because A requires B, and B exposes public type information about C. You have a public interface in B that inherits an interface in C.

Without A referencing C, A would have no idea what B's super type is. That information is required by .NET's metadata scheme.

Here is a very simple example of how to reproduce the problem. Assuming I used your exact code for Project B & C, this in project A will reproduce the problem:

```
namespace ProjectA
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private IPublicComponent d = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi vcsjones. Well I didn't use or implement the interface in ProjectA. Plus as I mentioned if I change the namespace for IPublicComponent, the problem goes away. One more point. Many other projects depend on ProjectB, I would expect them to complain as well.

Comment: @MBen Can you give a more concrete example in your question that will illustrate the problem more clearly then?

Comment: Well that the problem, I tried to reproduce it on a smaller scale, it didn't happen. I was looking for a way to get a verbose output from the C# compiler

Comment: @MBen Without knowing more about project A; it's hard to tell. My assumption right now is that you are using something in B (that you aren't aware of somehow) that depends on something in project C.

Comment: ProjecA definetly uses projectB. However when I added the new Interface to projectB and added to it a reference to ProjectC, I didn't expect the ProjectA to fail. The solution I work is huge, I am suspecting the compiler gets confused with namespaces. Any suggestion to where I should look?

Comment: I edited my question to show how "I fixed it". However this is not good, this is a public API I can't change the namespace.

Comment: This does not seem right. Compiler enforces references only when they are really needed i.e. code from ProjectC is actually used in ProjectA.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I was looking for some verbose output from the C# compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Project B has a dependance on the interface defined in Project C. So when you add a reference to project B the .Net framework identifies that the class implements the interface in project C, but it doesn't understand it, so for the framework to "understand" the interface, and therefore compile project B, it needs to know what the interface in Project C is.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have this:

```
ProjectC.ClassC1
ProjectB.ClassB1
ProjectB.ClassB2 : ProjectC.ClassC1
```

If your `ProjectA` uses anything from `ProjectB` it needs to reference at least `ProjectB`, obviously. For example if `ProjectA` uses `ProjectB.ClassB1` you only need to reference `ProjectB`. You **do not** have to reference `ProjectC` in this scenario though. But if in `ProjectA` you use `ProjectB.ClassB2` (which inherits/implements/uses `ProjectC.ClassC1`) you have to reference `ProjectC` as well.

So, if your `ProjectA` does not compile, somewhere in your code there is something that uses a code from `ProjectB` which in turn uses code from `ProjectC`.

I have just tested it myself. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

If you still have reference problems it's likely there is a corruption of references or something else has gone wrong. Try to remove and re-add references. Also have a look at project's source xml file. As the last thing you can try to re-create the project by creating it as new and adding all existing files to it.

Comment: Yes ProjectA uses ProjectB and has a reference to it. However the interface I added to ProjectB (implementing an interface in ProjectC) is not used in ProjectA. But somehow the compiler thinks it needs the reference to it. Resharper on the other hand sees that ProjectC is not used in ProjectA and is happy to delete it (unused references)

Comment: Clean solution, delete bin folders, rebuild solution.

Comment: Did that. If you see my Edit on how "I solved" that, you would see that's really a compiler getting confused with namespaces.

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes references get corrupted. Try to remove all references (in ProjectA and ProjectB) and re-add them. You can also check projects' source xml files.